# How could I sieve through the extra solutions to $\sin\theta +\cos\theta=\sin2\theta $in the interval $[-\pi,\pi]$?

Tags: trigonometry, solution-verification, problem-solving

> I am trying to find the number of solutions of the equation $$\sin\theta +\cos\theta=\sin2\theta $$ in the interval $[-\pi,\pi]$.

Here's what I did, $$\sin\theta +\cos\theta=\sin2\theta \\ \Rightarrow (\sin\theta +\cos\theta)^2=(\sin2\theta)^2 \\ \Rightarrow1+\sin2\theta=(\sin2\theta)^2$$

Hence we get $\sin2\theta=\frac{1\pm\sqrt{5}}{2}$, with $\sin2\theta=\frac{1 -\sqrt{5}}{2}$ bein the only valid solution.

Since $2\theta$ is present inside $\sin()$, I assumed that there would be four solutions of the equation. But on plotting the graph I find that there are only two solutions.

Why are there only two solution instead of four, and how could I prevent this mistake in future?

Comment: Your roots are incorrect (sign). Correct roots are $(1\pm \sqrt{5})/2$ which give two solutions only.

Comment: @MyMolecules Sorry typing error. I think I have fixed it.

Comment: In fact, the equation after the squaring has $4$ solutions in the given interval. See my answer below why.

Comment: @Peter Yes, I am aware of that. I mentioned in the question post. The question is how could I figure out the correct number of solutions without plotting a graph?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By only considering $\sin 2\theta=\dfrac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}$, one gets four roots since $\sin 2\theta$ has a period of $\pi$ and the interval $[-\pi,\pi]$ is twice that length.

But one also has to consider the equality of $\sin \theta + \cos \theta =\dfrac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}$. Since
$$\sin \theta + \cos \theta = \sqrt{2}\sin \left( \frac{\pi}{4} + \theta \right)$$

has a period of $2\pi$, actual number of roots is only $2$.

Answer (score 2):

OP: *how can I figure out the correct number of solutions without plotting a graph?*

*How can I prevent or atleast sieve though the extra solutions? The solutions of this equation itself are too complicated to check manually.*

1. Short of plugging the **candidate solutions** into the original
   equation, there is no general method for directly sifting out
   **extraneous** ones or determining how many there are.

   (If a calculator is allowed, it is typically a good-enough check to
   just plug in the *approximated* candidate solutions.)
2. However, it is possible to catch *potential* [extraneous solutions](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4419769/21813):
   carefully watch every line for [any step that is not obviously
   “reversible”](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3927547/21813),
   noting that *every* extraneous solution arises from such a step
   (which is not to say that every such step creates an extraneous
   solution):

   - [neglecting](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4452360/21813) [domain restrictions](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4326887/21813) typically of trigonometric and logarithmic functions
   - squaring an equation whose two sides don't identically have the same sign
   - converting absolute value to $\pm$

     $\lvert x+6\rvert=2x\\\pm(x+6)=2x\\x=-2 \;\text{ or }\; 6 \text{    (the negative solution is extraneous)}$
   - inadvertently multiplying an equation by $0$

     $x=1\\x^2=x\\x=0 \;\text{ or }\; 1$
   - performing some other non-injective operation on an equation.

Method 1 above is easier and safer than [Method 2](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4707692/21813).

Answer (score 1):

If you use the multiple angle formula $\theta=2 \tan^{-1}(x)$
$$\sin(\theta )+\cos(\theta)-\sin(2\theta)=0 \implies x^4-6 x^3+2 x-1=0$$ which has only two real solutions
$$x_1=\frac{3+\sqrt{5}}{2}+\sqrt{\frac{1}{2} \left(11+5 \sqrt{5}\right)}$$
$$x_2=\frac{3+\sqrt{5}}{2}-\sqrt{\frac{1}{2} \left(11+5 \sqrt{5}\right)}$$

Then $\theta_1 \sim 2.80847$ and $\theta_2 \sim -1.23768$ that you observed plotting.

Be always careful when you square.

Answer (score 1):

Avoid squaring whenever practicable as it often introduces

.  [When do we get extraneous roots?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/55445/when-do-we-get-extraneous-roots)

. [Extraneous Roots](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1513842/extraneous-roots)

et  $\sin\theta+\cos\theta=t,t^2=?\le1+1$

$t=t^2-1, 2t=\pm\sqrt5+1$

Now  clearly $(\sqrt5+1)^2>2$

$\implies\cos\left(\theta-\dfrac\pi4\right)=\dfrac t{\sqrt2}=?$

As $\cos(2\pi-y)=\cos y$ and cosine has a period $=2\pi,$ we shall have two incongruent solutions

Comment: Is $t=\frac{t^2-1}{2}$ correct? Shouldn't it be $t=t^2-1$?

Comment: @Alpha, thanks for your observations

Answer (score 0):

The squaring generated extra solutions. To see this , consider this simple example : $x=3$ has trivially a unique solution, but $x^2=9$ has $-3$ and $3$.

Comment: How can I prevent or atleast sieve though the extra solutions?

Comment: If you check all the solutions whether they satisfy the original equation, this is no problem. No idea whether there is an alternative approach working here avoiding this issue.

Comment: I don't think that's possible. The solutions of this equation itself are too complicated to check manually.