# Solving $|x-3|^{3x^2-10x+3}=1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms, exponentiation

Consider the equation $$|x-3|^{3x^2-10x+3}=1$$

Rewriting it in logarithmic form, $$\log_{|x-3|}1=3x^2-10x+3.$$

Since the base of a logarithm must be neither $0$ nor $1,$ $$3x^2-10x+3=0\\x=3\quad\text{or}\quad\frac13\\x=\frac13.$$

However, the given solution is $$x=\frac13\quad\text{or}\quad2\quad\text{or}\quad4.$$

Please tell me what I am missing here.

Comment: $|a|^b=1 \Leftrightarrow (|a|=1) \lor (|a|> 0 \land b=0)$

Comment: $a^b=c$ is not fully equivalent to $b=\log_a c$.

Comment: $0^0$ is an indeterminate form. There are circumstances in which it is conventionally set equal to $1$ [this allows some formulae and series to be consistent/valid when $n=0$]. However there is no indication of that in your question, and if used, it needs to be stated.

Comment: 1¹=1 , 1⁰=1 . From these equation 1=0 . How is it possible?

Comment: Just plug $x=2$ into the equation, and you will see instantly why it is a solution.

Answer (score 2):

1. By definition (the expression $\log_ax$ carries implicit
   conditions), $$a^y=x\quad\textbf{and}\quad
   a\in(0,1)\cup(1,\infty) \iff
   y=\log_ax.\tag1$$

   > $$|x-3|^{3x^2-10x+3}=1.$$ Rewriting it in logarithmic form, $$\log_{|x-3|}1=3x^2-10x+3.$$

   By the reverse direction of definition $(1),$ this step has
   restricted the solution set, so is invalid. Instead,
   $$|x-3|^{3x^2-10x+3}=1 \\\implies\\ \log_{|x-3|}1=3x^2-10x+3
   \quad\text{or}\quad |x-3|=1\quad\text{or}\quad |x-3|=0.$$

   The first disjunct gives the solution $\dfrac13$ (as you've shown),
   the second disjunct gives the remaining solutions $2$ and $4,$ while the third
   disjunct gives the [extraneous solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4330353/21813) $3.$
2. Actually, the logarithmic form is an unnecessary distraction in this exercise:
   \begin{align}{}&|x-3|^{3x^2-10x+3}=1\\\iff{}&|x-3|=1
   \quad\text{or}\quad \big(x-3\ne0 \quad\text{and}\quad
   3x^2-10x+3=0\big)\\\iff
   {}&x=\frac13\quad\text{or}\quad2\quad\text{or}\quad4.\end{align}

Comment: I am also confused about the solution 2 , |x-3| is always positive . So how it's answer can be 2

Comment: @VaibhavTiwari $|(2)-3|=|-1|$ is the absolute value of $-1;$ this absolute value equals $1,$ so is indeed positive. To be clear: $|x|$ is **not** saying that $x$ is positive; rather, it is telling u to drop any sign in front of $x.$

Comment: 1¹=1 , 1⁰=1 . From these equation 1=0 . How is it possible?

Comment: @VaibhavTiwari For functions like $f(x)=1^x$ that fail the [horizontal line test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horizontal_line_test), $$f(a)=f(b)\kern.6em\not\kern-.6em\implies a=b.$$