# Solving $\tan ^{-1}(\frac{1-x}{1+x})=\frac{1}{2}\tan ^{-1}(x)$

Tags: trigonometry, solution-verification

I was solving the following equation,$$\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{1-x}{1+x}\right)=\frac{1}{2}\tan ^{-1}\left(x\right)$$

But I missed a solution (don't know where's the mistake in my work).

---

***Here's my work:***
$$\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{1-x}{1+x}\right)=\frac{1}{2}\tan ^{-1}\left(x\right)$$
Putting $x = \tan(\theta)$
$$\begin{align} \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{1-\tan\theta}{1+\tan\theta}\right)&=\frac{1}{2}\tan ^{-1}\left(\tan\theta\right)\\
\tan ^{-1}\left(\tan\left(\frac\pi 4 - \theta\right)\right)&=\frac{1}{2}\theta\\
\frac\pi 4 - \theta&=\frac{1}{2}\theta\\
\frac\pi 4&=\frac{1}{2}\theta + \theta\\
\frac\pi 4&=\frac{3}{2}\theta\\
\frac\pi 6&=\theta\\
\frac\pi 6&=\tan^{-1}(x)\\
\tan\frac\pi 6&=(x)\\
\frac1{\sqrt{3}}&=x\end{align}$$

---

I got only one solution, but the answer in my textbook is $\pm\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$. Where is the mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> $$\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{1-x}{1+x}\right)=\frac{1}{2}\tan ^{-1}\left(x\right)$$
> Putting $x = \tan(\theta)$

Here, it is useful to impose the restriction $$\theta\in\left(-\frac\pi2,-\frac\pi4\right)\cup\left(-\frac\pi4,\frac\pi2\right);\tag1$$ since $\tan\theta$ for which the given equation is defined is surjective on this interval, this restriction is valid and does not contract the solution set.

> \begin{align} \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{1-\tan\theta}{1+\tan\theta}\right)&=\frac{1}{2}\tan ^{-1}\left(\tan\theta\right)\\
> \tan ^{-1}\left(\tan\left(\frac\pi 4 - \theta\right)\right)&=\frac{1}{2}\theta\\
> \frac\pi 4 - \theta&=\frac{1}{2}\theta\end{align}

Note that $$\arctan(\tan \alpha)\not\equiv \alpha;\tag{*}$$ [instead](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/1d4hmjk2xv), for each $\alpha\in\mathbb R,$ there is some $k\in\mathbb Z$ such that $$\arctan(\tan \alpha)=\alpha+k\pi.$$ By condition $(1),$ $$\arctan \left(\tan\theta\right)=\theta$$ while \begin{align}\arctan\left(\tan\left(\frac\pi4 -\theta\right)\right)&=\frac\pi4 -\theta \quad\text{or}\quad \left(\frac\pi4 -\theta\right)-\pi\\
&=\frac\pi4 -\theta \quad\text{or}\quad -\frac34\pi -\theta.\end{align}

> \begin{align} \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{1-\tan\theta}{1+\tan\theta}\right)&=\frac{1}{2}\tan ^{-1}\left(\tan\theta\right)\end{align}

Continuing with your substitution method:
\begin{align}
\frac12\arctan \left(\tan\theta\right) &=\arctan\left(\tan\left(\frac\pi4 -\theta\right)\right)\\
\frac12\big(\theta\big) &= \left(\frac\pi4 -\theta\right) \quad\text{or}\quad \left(-\frac34\pi -\theta\right)\\
\theta &= \frac\pi6 \quad\text{or}\quad -\frac\pi2\\
&= \frac\pi6\\
x&=\frac1{\sqrt3}.\end{align} Plugging this value into the given equation reveals that [it is the only solution](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/wo54hdjncl). So, while you had obtained the correct solution set by serendipity (without proper justification), your textbook is actually wrong too in neglecting to eliminate its [extraneous solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4330353/21813) $x=-\dfrac1{\sqrt3}.$

Comment: This is the only correct answer since it mentions $\arctan({\tan\alpha})\neq \alpha$

Comment: Thank you, that's totally different from what I've been taught in school.

Comment: My solution is not properly justified because I didn't restrict the value of $\theta$ to $\left(-\dfrac{\pi}{2}, \dfrac{\pi}{2}\right)$. Right?

Comment: @Yooo No: restricting $\theta$ to $\arctan$'s principal range makes your substitution $x=\tan\theta$ injective, which merely makes it subsequently easier to recover $x,$ but this step is not crucial. Your mistake is in using the false identity $\arctan(\tan \alpha)\equiv \alpha.$

Comment: Ohhh, actually in my textbook, they are given as identities that, $\arcsin(\sin(x)) = x, \arccos(\cos(x)) = x ...$ for the 6 trig. functions.

Comment: @Yooo Since $\arccos(\cos(2\pi))=0,$ we also know that $\arccos(\cos(x))$ does not generally equal $x$ either. Similarly for $\sin.$ The equalities do hold though for all $x$ in the principal range.

Comment: Yes. The point is that these identities work well only when $x$ lies in the [principal branch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_branch) *which the book doesn't mention*.

Comment: Yes exactly! I think I should buy a better book lol

Answer (score 1):

Apply $tan$ to both sides

$ \dfrac{1 - x}{1 + x} = \tan \left( \dfrac{1}{2} \tan^{-1}(x) \right) \\
= \dfrac{ x }{ \sqrt{1 + x^2} + 1 } $

From this,

$ (1 - x) (\sqrt{1 + x^2} + 1 ) = x (1 + x) $

$ (1 - x) \sqrt{1 + x^2} + 1 - x = x + x^2  $

$ \sqrt{ 1 + x^2} = \dfrac{(x^2 + 2 x - 1)}{ ( 1 - x)} $

$ 1 + x^2 = \dfrac{ (x^2 + 2x - 1)^2 }{ (x - 1)^2 } $

$ (x^2 + 1) (x - 1)^2 = (x^2 + 2 x - 1)^2 $

$ (x^2 + 1)(x^2 - 2 x + 1) = x^4 + 4 x^2 + 1 + 4 x^3 - 4 x - 2 x^2 $

$ x^4 - 2 x^3 + x^2 + x^2 - 2 x + 1 = x^4 + 4 x^3 + 2 x^2 - 4 x + 1 $

Cancelling $x^4 $ and $1$ on both sides, and re-arranging,

$ 6 x^3 - 2 x = 0 $

Dividing by $(2 x)$ (The root $0$ is extraneous)

$ 3 x^2 - 1 = 0 $

Hence, $ x = \pm \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{3}} $

Comment: How did you get $\frac{ x }{ \sqrt{1 + x^2} + 1 }$ from $\tan(\frac12\tan^{-1}(x))$? May you explain please?

Comment: $\tan(\frac{1}{2} \phi) = \dfrac{ \sin(\frac{1}{2} \phi )}{\cos(\frac{1}{2} \phi) } = \dfrac{ \cos(\frac{1}{2} \phi) \sin(\frac{1}{2} \phi)}{ \cos^2(\frac{1}{2} \phi)} = \dfrac{ \sin(\phi) }{1 + \cos(\phi) } \\ = \dfrac{ \tan(\phi) }{ \sec(\phi) + 1 } \\ = \dfrac{ \tan(\phi) }{ \sqrt{\tan^2(\phi) + 1} + 1 } $

Answer (score 1):

Thank you to @Robin'sPremiumCoffee for a nice algebraic solution. Now the problem with your original method is that although:
$$\frac{1-\tan \theta}{1+\tan \theta} = \tan(\frac \pi 4 -\theta)$$
It is also equal to:
$$\frac{1-\tan \theta}{1+\tan \theta} = \tan(\frac \pi 4 -\theta)=\tan(\pi +\frac \pi 4 -\theta)$$
This is because $\tan(\theta)$ is $\pi$ periodic. From there we may continue your steps to get:
\begin{align} 
\pi + \frac\pi 4 - \theta&=\frac{1}{2}\theta\\
\frac{5\pi} 4&=\frac{1}{2}\theta + \theta\\
\frac{5\pi} 4&=\frac{3}{2}\theta\\
\frac{5\pi} 6&=\theta\\
\frac{5\pi}6&=\tan^{-1}(x)\\
\tan\frac{5\pi} 6&=(x)\\
-\frac1{\sqrt{3}}&=x\end{align}